# IIS Rewrite - Redirect Rule and Add Response Header together

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

In IIS, I have a set of redirect rules using IIS Rewrite module. In that, I would like to redirect an URL as well as add custom header to the response. I have setup redirect rule and an outbound rule to set the headers. It seems that when a redirect is initiated by the rule, then outbound rules are not executed. Is there a way to do both?